# Integral of complex argument

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Does the following converge:
$$\sum_n\int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty}\frac{\vert\arg(1+z^2/n^4)\vert}{\vert z\vert^2}dz,$$
where $\arg$ denotes the complex argument. I tried to solve it using the definition of the complex argument with the pi minus the arctangent but the expression became to complicated. Notice that it is very ease to prove that the integral byitself converges for every $n$, since we can just apply $\arg z<\pi$ but the problem is that we have the summation of all these $n$ terms.

Remark: If you find it easier you can replace the argument with the principal logarithm and my question is the same.